# Override aesthetics of custom plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, inext

I am not sure exactly how to override aesthetic properties of a custom plot made with ggplot. The only way I could think of right now was using the functionality of the `grid` package, though is really hackish. Maybe there is a easier way, like using `guides` or so from `ggplot2`, though I could't manage to make it work?

Below is an example where I just want to adjust the line width in the graph. Of course, I would like that to trickle down in the legend as well. So, below are my steps with `grid`, but any simpler solution is greatly appreciated (ideally something that doesn't need `grid` but just `ggplot2`, if possible).

```r
library(iNEXT)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

# Some custom plot from the iNEXT package
data(spider)
out <- iNEXT(spider, q=0, datatype="abundance")

custom_plot <- ggiNEXT(out)
custom_plot
```

[image]

```r
# Get the grobs
g <- grid.force(ggplotGrob(custom_plot))

# Check the list of names of grobs:
# grid.ls(g) 
# View(g$grobs)

# Get an idea about the grob paths
gpaths <- paste(gsub(pattern = "layout::", 
                     replacement = "", 
                     x = grid.ls(g, print = FALSE)$gPath), 
                grid.ls(g, print = FALSE)$name, 
                sep = "::")
gpaths[grepl("polyline", gpaths)]
#> [1] "panel.7-5-7-5::grill.gTree.114::panel.grid.minor.y..polyline.107"            
#> [2] "panel.7-5-7-5::grill.gTree.114::panel.grid.minor.x..polyline.109"            
#> [3] "panel.7-5-7-5::grill.gTree.114::panel.grid.major.y..polyline.111"            
#> [4] "panel.7-5-7-5::grill.gTree.114::panel.grid.major.x..polyline.113"            
#> [5] "panel.7-5-7-5::GRID.polyline.91"                                             
#> [6] "panel.7-5-7-5::geom_ribbon.gTree.101::geom_ribbon.gTree.95::GRID.polyline.93"
#> [7] "panel.7-5-7-5::geom_ribbon.gTree.101::geom_ribbon.gTree.99::GRID.polyline.97"

# Edit the width of the lines
g <- editGrob(grob = g, 
              gPath = gpaths[grepl("panel.7-5-7-5::GRID.polyline", gpaths)],
              gp = gpar(lwd = c(1,1,1,1)))
plot(g)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is under "***Draw R/E curves by yourself***" at
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iNEXT/vignettes/Introduction.html.

Fortunately,  the authors of the package have provided the function **fortify()** along with some code to copy verbatim, to achieve what you desire.

You should copy the following from that section and change the **lwd** (line width) parameter in the **geom_line()** function call to your liking.

```
df <- fortify(out, type=1) # Note the type parameter!

df.point <- df[which(df$method=="observed"),]
df.line <- df[which(df$method!="observed"),]
df.line$method <- factor(df.line$method, 
                         c("interpolated", "extrapolated"),
                         c("interpolation", "extrapolation"))
 
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=site)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=site), size=5, data=df.point) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=method), lwd=1.5, data=df.line) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=y.lwr, ymax=y.upr,
                  fill=site, colour=NULL), alpha=0.2) +
  labs(x="Number of individuals", y="Species diversity") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        text=element_text(size=18),
        legend.box = "vertical")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making life overly complicated.  Does this approach gives you what you need?

Generate a plot

```
plot <- mtcars %>% ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=mpg, y=cyl, colour=as.factor(gear)))
plot
```

[image: original plot]

Modify the plot

```
plot + aes(size=5) + guides(size=FALSE)
```

[image: modified plot]

The `guides` call suppresses the legend for `size`.  Obviously, you can delete it if you do want the legend to appear.

***Update***

Responding to OP's question in the comments. I agree: my suggestion does not modify the `ggiNEXT` plot as I predicted.

I've done some digging.  The diversity curves in the plot are produced by the following statement in the `ggiNEXT.iNEXT` function

```
g <- g + geom_line(aes_string(linetype = "lty"), lwd = 1.5) + ...
```

I find this strange.  As far as I know, `lwd` is not an aesthetic in `ggplot2`. (And `"lty"` is not a valid value for the `linetype` aesthetic.  However, `lty` and `lwd` are the base R equivalents of `ggplot2`'s `linetype` and `size` respectively.)

In case `lwd` was an undocumented feature, I tried

```
custom_plot + aes(lwd=3)
```

But this had no effect.

I then copied the body of the `ggiNEXT.iNEXT` function into my own function and changed the call to `geom_line` to read

```
g <- g + geom_line(aes_string(linetype = "lty"), size = 1.5)
```

Calling my new function produced a plot identical (to my eye at least) to that produced by the original `ggiNEXT.iNEXT` call. Then

```
custom_plot <- myPlot(out)
custom_plot
custom_plot + aes(size=3) + guides(size=FALSE)
```

Produced the predicted changes.  So my best suggestion is either (1) to create a local version of `ggiNEXT.iNEXT` and load it whenever you need to make this modification [Of course, you then need to make sure you update your local copy in line with any changes to the "official" version] or (2) to create the graph from scratch.  Looking at the source code for `ggiNEXT.iNEXT`, it's not that complicated.

This might be worth raising as an issue with the authors of `iNEXT`.

Comment: Hi @Limey, have you tried your proposed solution on the provided iNEXT custom plot? I purposely created that example. I don't seem to get the expected results.

Comment: Valentin, no, I haven't.  Simply because I didn't spot that your input data was a package dataset.  Apologies.  I don't have the iNEXT package installed, but I will see what I can do.